# NestJS - Mongoose discriminator key won't be filled up automatically

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

The `discriminatorKey` won't be filled up automatically. In other words, I cannot find the `kind` field on the saved document.

**Database Module**

```js
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: User.name,
        schema: UserSchema,
        discriminators: [
          { name: Fan.name, schema: FanSchema },
        ],
      },
    ]),
  ],
  exports: [MongooseModule],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

**User Schema**

```js
@Schema({ discriminatorKey: 'kind' })
export class User {
  @Prop({ enum: [Fan.name], required: true })
  kind: string;

  @Prop()
  displayName: string;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

**Fan Schema**

```js
@Schema()
export class Fan {
  kind: string;

  displayName: string;
}

export const FanSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Fan);
```

**Save a Document**

```js
const userObj = new Fan();
userObj.displayName = "Sam";

return this.userModel.create(userObj);
```

Comment: I'm trying to make something similar work. How are you able to access 'displayName' on 'Fan' since the class itself doesn't inherit User? How does TS allow this?

Comment: Sorry, I've just now seen that you also have 'displayName' explicitly declared on the 'Fan' class. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was injecting the wrong model, that's why the `discriminatorKey` couldn't be filled up automatically.

**Wrong Use**

```js
constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private readonly userModel: Model<User>) {}
```

**Correct Use**

```js
constructor(@InjectModel(Fan.name) private readonly fanModel: Model<Fan>) {}
```